# Genexus - Disable Text Block used as button

Tags: button, hide, textblock, genexus

I have a Text Block that I use as a button (with enter event) and when I press it it takes a while to do what it has to do, so you can click more than once the button and it does it twice or more times. So what I want to do is to disable or to hide the text block while its doing its job, but the text block only hides when it exits the enter event, which is to late because I already could pressed several times the buttom.

How can I find a solution for this? Is there a way to disable or hide the text block when I enter the enter event but before it exit the event?

Comment: Which version of GeneXus are you using? This problem has been fixed recently.

Comment: Oh, Im using GeneXus X Evolution 1 Version 10.1.32504 U2.5

Thank you for answering. What I did to make it work was using param session variables.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are calling a procedure. Try to use

```
MyProcedure.Submit()
```

instead of

```
MyProcedure.Call()
```

Comment: Thank you. I`ll try that